# How to disable semeru 11 default dump behavior?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm on semeru 11.

When my program crashes, I see this line, which takes a long time.

```
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "abort", detail "" at 2023/04/24 02:15:30 - please wait.
```

I tried disabling with JVM switch:

```
-Xdump:java:none
```

But to no avail. Is there a way to disable the take dump on crash behavior of semeru 11?

Comment: You're encountering an hard trouble: only those can create a dump. I suggest you to show us if a part of that dump gives clues about what is happening, because it's not the normal behavior of Java (in case of application errors), and you can't avoid correcting that trouble.